# Proxy methods not working in sfGuardSecurityUser

Tags: php, methods, symfony1, proxy, sfdoctrineguard

I am developing a filter in Symfony to keep track of certain request that users perform within the application. In order to retrieve the current user I use the `getContext()` method:

```
$user = $this->getContext()->getUser();
```

And then I try to access its properties:

```
...
$username = $user->getUsername();
...
```

The problem is that Symfony raises the following exception: *Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object in ... sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php*, unless I retrieve the user this way:

```
$user = $this->getContext()->getUser()->getGuardUser();
```

According to [sfDoctrineGuardUser documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) (and source code) there are proxy methods like this:

```
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->getGuardUser()->getUsername();
}
```

Why the proxy method is not working?

**UPDATE**

After a couple of weeks developing, the problem arose again. This time from a view using the `$sf_user` variable. I can get the ID with

```
$sf_user->getGuardUser()->getId()
```

but not with

```
$sf_user->getId()
```

In my own answer below is the explanation.

Comment: You've definitely changed your myUser class to extend sfGuardSecurityUser, yes? (And when odd things are going on, always good to clear your cache, too, just in case...)

Comment: Yes, myUser inherits from sfGuardSecurityUser and I've clean the cache several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt Gibson comment I reviewed the installation process of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. It seems I made a typo somewhere because now everything works well, both

```
$this->getGuardUser()->getUsername()
```

and

```
$this->getUsername()
```

However, I think these proxy methods could be improved because it lacks of a `getId` method. You can retrieve almost everything except ID, which must be retrieved using the long form:

```
$this->getGuardUser()->getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `$this->getGuardUser()` returns null, you have to find out why.

Comment: I think that cannot be the problem, since calling `$this->getGuardUser()` (a method of `sfGuardSecurityUser` as well) returns the object properly. If you inspect the source code you realize that proxy methods are simple shortcuts to `getGuardUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your proxy methods to your User class, there aren't that many of them.

```
class myUser extends sfGuardSecurityUser
{
  public function getId()
  {
    return $this->getGuardUser()->getId();
  }
  public function getUsername()
  {
    return $this->getGuardUser()->getUsername();
  }
}
```

Or, if you like magic, you can define virtual __call() method and redirect all undefined methods to parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug in the version of sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php that I have. Look around line 202 and change this... This was causing that IF statement not to fire thus NOT returning a user when needed.

```
if (!$this->user && $id = $this->getAttribute('user_id', null, 'sfGuardSecurityUser'))
{
```

to

```
$id = $this->getAttribute('user_id', null, 'sfGuardSecurityUser');
if (!$this->user)
{
```